# Complex SQL query over four tables does not fetch wanted result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Imagine the following scenario: Employees of a company can give votes to an arbitrary question (integer value).

I have a complex request where I want to fetch five information:

1. Name of the company
2. Average vote value per company
3. Number of employees
4. Number of votes
5. Participation (no of votes/no of employees)

The SQL query shall only fetch votes of companies, that the current user is employed at.

Therefore I am accessing four different tables, following you see an excerpt of the table declarations:

```
User
- id

Company
- id
- name

Employment
- user_id (FK User.id)
- company_id (FK Company.id)

Vote
- company_name
- vote_value
- timestamp
```

`User` and `Company` are related by an `Employment` (n:m relation, but needs to be extra table). The table `Vote` shall not be connected by PK/FK-relation, but they can be related to a company by their company name (`Company.name = Vote.company_name`).

I managed to fetch all information **except for the number of employees** correctly by the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    c.name AS company,
    AVG(v.vote_value) AS value,
    COUNT(e.user_id) AS employees,
    COUNT(f.face) AS votes,
    (COUNT(e.user_id) / COUNT(v.vote_value)) AS participation
FROM Company c
JOIN Employment e ON e.company_id = c.id
JOIN User u ON u.id = e.user_id
JOIN Vote v
    ON v.company_name = c.name
    AND YEAR(v.timestamp) = :year
    AND MONTH(v.timestamp) = :month
    AND DAY(v.timestamp) = :day
WHERE u.id = :u_id
GROUP BY v.company_name, e.company_id
```

But instead of fetching the correct number of employees, the `employee` field is always equal the number of votes. (And therefore the `participation` value is also wrong.)

Is there any way to perform this **in one query without subqueries**<sup>1</sup>? What do I have to change so that the query fetches the correct number of employees?

<sup>1</sup> I am using Doctrine2 and try to avoid subqueries as Doctrine does not support them. I just did not want to pull this into a Doctrine discussion. That's I why I broke this topic down to SQL level.

Comment: Why is a vote using `company_name` instead of a `company_id` as a foreign key?

Comment: The voting table shall not have any PK/FK relation to any other table. It shall be an isolated table by design.

Comment: a quick look at the query, you just need `GROUP BY e.company_id`

Comment: Also I usually like to build the query bit by bit, testing it as I add things to it and see which part breaks stuff.

Comment: @Populus: No, changing the `GROUP BY` by is not helping.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel well that comment wasn't supposed to solve it :P Or I'd be posting an answer :P It was just an observation that 1 of the groupbys was redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch the number of employees then the issue is that you are filtering by only 1 employee:

```
WHERE u.id = :u_id
```

Secondly, bear in mind that if you want to count the amount of employees and you have gotten into the vote grouping level, then of course you will have the amount of rows equal to the amount of votes. So you will have to distinct count as @Przem... mentioned:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_id) AS employees,
```

That way you will uniquely count the employees for the company (getting rid of the repeated employee ids for all the votes the employee has).

As you mentioned in a comment:

> It returns the 1 as employee count

This is because of the where condition forcing to 1 employee with many votes. The distinct will only count the unique 1 employee filtered by the `where` clause and that is why you get only 1. However, that is the correct result (based on your filter condition).

Adding subqueries in the `select` clause will also get you to the right result but at the expense of performance.

Comment: ha! I didn't even notice that... end of the day tiredness o.o

Comment: Interesting to know. That means there is no way that I can perform this in one query (without subqueries)?

Comment: You can - check out my revised solution.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel As mentioned in the answer, you have to use the `distinct` :)

Comment: But as soon as I use `DISTINCT` I cannot use the `u.id = :u_id` statement anymore, or can I?

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Yes, you can... but you won't be fetching data for a COMPANY level but rather a USER level. So you can't get the whole company data if you add the user filtering condition. If you want to get whole company data and also data filtered for a specific user there is no way to that without a subquery OR running 2 separate queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this--it calculates the votes as one subquery and the employees as another subquery.

```
SELECT c.name,
ce.employee_count,
cv.vote_count,
cv.vote_count / ce.employee_count,
cv.vote_value
FROM 
(select company, count(*) AS 'employee_count' 
FROM employment GROUP BY company) ce
INNER JOIN company c
ON c.id = ce.company
INNER  JOIN 
(select company, AVG(vote_value) AS 'vote_value', count(*) as 'vote_count'
FROM vote v GROUP BY company) cv
ON c.id = cv.company
```

Comment: As I am using Doctrine2 I would like to avoid subqueries (as Doctrine2 does not support them. I was just breaking down the problem to the SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think with a query defined like that you should add the **DISTINCT** keyword while counting the number of employees:

```
SELECT
    c.name AS company,
    AVG(v.vote_value) AS value,
    COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_id) AS employees,
    COUNT(f.face) AS votes,
    (COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_id) / COUNT(v.vote_value)) AS participation
FROM Company c
JOIN Employment e ON e.company_id = c.id
JOIN User u ON u.id = e.user_id
JOIN Vote v
    ON v.company_name = c.name
    AND YEAR(v.timestamp) = :year
    AND MONTH(v.timestamp) = :month
    AND DAY(v.timestamp) = :day
GROUP BY v.company_name, e.company_id;
```

Not sure if it is possible in MySQL, though.

Edit: as @Mosty Mostacho pointed out, the condition on u.id was the problem, and without it and with addition of DISTINCT keyword, the query returns correct results and I edited the above query.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. It returns the `1` as employee count.

Comment: But I have to pass the `u.id` anyhow. It shall only fetch votes of company the current user is employed at. I will update this in my question.

Comment: Then you should have a condition on company's id, not on employee's (if you do not want to use a subquery). Just fetch the employee's company id before and use a condition: c.id = :company_id